# Filtering git branches in github actions/workflows

Tags: git, github-actions, git-branch

I want to deploy code based on the latest cut branch in git. Branch names follow this scheme:

```
release-2022.1
release-2022.2
...
[release-yyyy.m]
```

Is there a way in github workflows to filter out the latest releases?
Limit to last 5 releases.

In other words,

1. can I filter git branches by name (release*)?
2. then sort git branches
3. in decending order? then filter the 5 most recent branches at the
   top?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

`git branch -r --sort=-committerdate | grep -E 'release-\d{4}.\d{1}`